# Chromonica (chromatic harmonica) notes relating to holes

Tags: harmonica, chromatic-harmonica

I have several chromonicas from the 50s/60s, and none seem to be 'standard'. There is only the one C/B hole in each octave, whereas it appears that standard includes two C holes (in a C instrument) next to each other. So it's blow/draw for C/D E/F G/A, and draw/blow for B/C.

They aren't be-bop or blues. classical, solo or minor tuned, and certainly not Richter, so what are they?

There's one which plays in C# when the button's out, and C when pushed in. It's stamped C, and *may* be 'Irish tuning', but with some delving, Irish tuned harmonicas drop from C to B when the button is used, so it maybe isn't that.

Using an interesting *harminoca* tag...

**EDIT**  I just can't believe it ! I checked again, and yes, it has **two** C notes in holes adjacent to each other! Been playing on and off for a very long time, and honestly thought there was only the one C. Perhaps as a kid I automatically by-passed the 'other C' each time, so didn't actively think it existed. Sorry to cause any confusion - I guess the question is now null and void - except for the backwards harmonica.

Not a complete idiot - I just help them out when they're short...

Comment: Could you be more specific about the harmonica models, and either be more specific about how they diverge from solo tuning (which holes play which notes) or map out the note layout?

Comment: Larry Adler professional; 64 chromonica; Chromonika III; Chromonica II deluxe; Chrometta 10.All have blow/draw - C/D, E/F, G/A and draw/blow B/C, all the way along.

Comment: _I just can't believe it ! I checked again, and yes, it has two C notes in holes adjacent to each other!!_ This is very disappointing...

Comment: _Irish tuned harmonicas drop from C to B_ - If it's tuned that way. I think the point of Irish tuning is to drop half a step - regardless of key. But C# is a weird key to start with. I see @Some_Guy gave you the answer anyhow.

Comment: @Stinkfoot - true, the idea of Irish tuning *is* to drop down into B. Reason given in Wiki is that a lot of Irish tunes are in G or D, but the relevance of *that* escapes me. What's B got to do with G or D??

Comment: _What's B got to do with G or D_ I don't know why B should be of such importance to those keys, no - but I don't know anything about Irish music either. I thought it said someplace that Irish music had a lot of minor notes, etc. That makes sense: you'd like to be able to drop down half a step from the root instead of having to having to work backwards with enharmonics, etc.

Comment: @Stinkfoot - There's a lot of Irish tunes in Dorian and Mixolydian, (and Aeolian), but how that translates back to B major, I don't know. In fact, from where I see it, it doesn't. Another question spawned?

Comment: @Tim as I've said before, don't use wikipedia for a reference about harmonica, there is misinformation and information in equal measure.  In regards to "Irish Tuning".  I've never heard of it.  It may be a legitimate thing, or it may just be something that one guy uses in one place and decided to go down in history by adding it to the wiki.  Wikipedia is good for some things but for harmonica it is an absolute joke.

Comment: @Tim - I don't see how it has anything to do with B major, but if you're playing C Dorian, Mixolydian or Aeolian, being able to quickly drop down a half step to Bb or Eb or Ab just by hitting the slide on that hole is cool.

Comment: @Tim - There are chroms today in a lot of different keys. One of the most popular seems to be one that's tuned to B - I surmise it's because by moving the slide you're in C. I was thinking of getting one: If your default mode of playing is with the slide in, then you've got "Irish tuning" - great for the modes you mentioned. Or you coul flip it over, like your weird C# chrom - then you'd have authentic "irish tuning".

Comment: @Some_Guy - "Irish tuning" is legit. See: [**_Irish Fiddle Tuning...At this stage, knowledge of the Eddie Clarke tuning (aka Irish tuning) is common..._**](http://eugeneryan.blogspot.com/2014/11/overview-i-came-up-with-tuning-few_14.html) .

Comment: @Tim: [**_Irish Fiddle Tuning...At this stage, knowledge of the Eddie Clarke tuning (aka Irish tuning) is common..._**](http://eugeneryan.blogspot.com/2014/11/overview-i-came-up-with-tuning-few_14.html) .

Comment: _and honestly thought there was only the one C_  On a standard chrom in C major there are actually 3 C's. Blow on hole 4 and slide and you get B#, or C, depending on how you use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So it's blow/draw for C/D E/F G/A, and draw/blow for B/C.

This seems to fit with the standard tuning for a chromatic, "solo" tuning, which is the following repeated pattern:

```
       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10… etc.
       ------------------------------------
blow: |C |E |G |C |C |E |G |C |C |E...etc.
draw: |D |F |A |B |D |F |A |B |D |F...etc
       ------------------------------------
```

In which the blow note C is found repeated, as the end of one octave, then the beginning of the next.

On a chromatic harmonica this therefore results in 3 ways to play C, the 4 blow, 5 blow, and the 4 draw with the slide in, and 2 "C holes": one a C/D hole and the other a C/B hole.

A tuning without a repeated C would be like one of the following:

"Bebop":

```
       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10… etc.
       ------------------------------------
blow: |C |E |G |Bb|C |E |G |Bb|C |E...etc.
draw: |D |F |A |B |D |F |A |B |D |F...etc
       ------------------------------------
```

F6/G6  (starting from -2 reflects the easiest way to retune from a stock harp: from an F chromatic)

```
     (-2)(-1)1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10… etc.
       ------------------------------------
blow: |F |A |C |D |F |A |C |D |F |A |C |D...etc.
draw: |G |B |D |E |G |B |D |E |G |B |D |E...etc.
       ------------------------------------
```

As for the C# harp, it may simply be that the slider is on backwards, so in/out is reversed for all notes, does this fit with your experience?  Is the blow chord a Db/C# major chord and the draw an Eb/D# minor 6 chord?)

Comment: Having a very off day today! Looking as closely as I should have before posing the question, the 'backwards' one does appear to have the slide in the opposite way to the other harmonicas, which would go along with your suggestion.